# Getting frame variables from Python Runtime - pycharm

Tags: performance, pycharm

After updating to PyCharm 2019. my programs run incredibly slowly and with every command in the python console I can see a background task running "getting frame variables from python runtime".
This was not happening in the older version of the IDE and it has made my programs incredibly slow. Any pointers on whats happening and how I can resolve this?

Comment: It is a reported issue, check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-43295

Answer (score 2):

Make sure uncheck the box indicated:
[image]

Comment: Which box is that supposed to be pointing to?

Comment: The third one. However, sometimes Even if you uncheck the third box, problems are still there in some Pycharm editions.