# PyCharm 2020.2 running very slow - stuck at getting frame variables from python runtime

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm started running very slowly, especially when running the code in the Python Console. It gets stuck in Getting Frame Variables from Python RunTime[image]

I have a 16 GB RAM. Running Pycharm 2020.2 Professional Edition.

The problem appears when I run a code that loads a 500000x60 csv (80mb). However I run the code in the past with no issues.

I started noticing this super slow behavior roughly from a moment when I created a folder (inside the project directory) with 50k csv files.
I already tried to exclude this and other folders from the project but didn't help.

I'm aware of other similar questions like [Getting frame variables from Python Runtime - pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508692/getting-frame-variables-from-python-runtime-pycharm) but wasn't helpful.

Comment: It is so. If you disable the "variable view", you get better speed. I just avoid to use large dataset in pycharm console (I use console only for short test, and a normal run for large dataset). Else Spyder is much more responsive on large dataframes (for the few time I need to work on large dataframe interactively).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Even if I turn off the box "Show console variables by default", the problem keeps being there